# RSpec test runs correctly only when run in sequence

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I have an issue that seems to be specific to my test suite.

I have a module that holds some defaults in a constant like so:

```
module MyModule

  DEFAULTS = {
    pool: 15
  }
  def self.options
    @options ||= DEFAULTS
  end

  def self.options=(opts)
    @options = opts
  end

end

module MyModule
  class MyClass

    def options
      MyModule.options
    end

    def import_options(opts)
      MyModule.options = opts
    end

  end
end
```

I allow the program to boot with no options or a user can specify options.  If no options are given, we use the defaults but if options are given we use that instead.  An example test suite looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe MyModule::MyClass do
  context "with deafults" do
    let(:my) { MyModule::MyClass.new }
    it 'has a pool of 15' do
      expect(my.options[:pool]).to eq 15
    end
  end
  context "imported options" do
    let(:my) { MyModule::MyClass.new }
    it 'has optional pool size' do
      my.import_options(pool: 30)
      expect(my.options[:pool]).to eq 30
    end
  end
end
```

If those tests run in order, great, everything passes.  If it runs in reverse (where the second test goes first), the first test gets a pool size of 30.

I don't have a 'real world' scenario where this would happen, the program boots once and that's it but I'd like to test for this accordingly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@options` is a class variable in that module.  I'm not sure that is technically the right name for it, but that's how it is acting.  As an experiment, print out `@options.object_id` right before you access it in `self.options`.  Then run your tests.  You'll see that in both cases it prints out the same id.  This is why when your tests are flipped you get 30.  `@options` is already defined so `@options ||= DEFAULTS` is not setting `@options` to `DEFAULTS`.

```
$ cat foo.rb
module MyModule

  DEFAULTS = {
    pool: 15
  }
  def self.options
    puts "options_id: #{@options.object_id}"
    @options ||= DEFAULTS
  end

  def self.options=(opts)
    @options = opts
  end
end

module MyModule
  class MyClass

    def options
      MyModule.options
    end

    def import_options(opts)
      MyModule.options = opts
    end

  end
end

puts "pool 30"
my = MyModule::MyClass.new
my.import_options(pool: 30)
my.options[:pool]

puts
puts "defaults"
my = MyModule::MyClass.new
my.options[:pool]
```

And running it...

```
$ ruby foo.rb
pool 30
options_id: 70260665635400

defaults
options_id: 70260665635400
```

Comment: Yep, I noticed the same thing - is there a way to "teardown" the constants between tests?

Comment: They are reset when you load the file again. `load(<path-to-file>)`

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a [before(:each)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks)

```
before(:each) do
  MyModule.options = MyModule::DEFAULTS
end
```

Side note - maybe a class for the configuration.

Something like:

```
module MyModule
  class Configuration
    def initialize
      @foo = 'default'
      @bar = 'default'
      @baz = 'default'
    end

    def load_from_yaml(path)
      # :)
    end

    attr_accessor :foo, :bar, :baz
  end
end
```

And then you could add something like this:

```
module MyModule
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  # MyModule.configure do |config|
  #   config.baz = 123
  # end
  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end
end
```

And finally you will reset the configuration in a more meaningful manner

```
before(:each) do
  MyModule.configuration = MyModule::Configuration.new
end
```